# How to disable http requests and use https exclusively with Jetty 7

Tags: http, https, jetty

I haven't found an answer yet, but maybe someone else's Google foo is better than mine.

I have an osgi enabled project using karaf as our wrapper with jetty.  We would like to completely disable the http pipe, but so far all I have found online is how to turn on the SSL authentication which we already have running.  We enabled this in the jetty.xml file by adding a connector.

I have tried removing/commenting out the other connector:

```
<!-- <Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8181"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call> -->
```

But this had no effect on disallowing http calls to our services.  We also do not want to simply re-direct clients from http to https.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fully disable HTTP especially if I don't care about http to https re-directs, I wouldn't mess with jetty.xml at all. I would rather close http ports 80/8080 or whatever I configured Jetty to use. If you're using linux you do this by setting firewall rules. Firewall is the first line of defence and your http request would not even make it to Jetty process. Off course I am assuming you're have control over your server's firewall.